# RSyslog post processing and remote forwarding

Tags: logging, debian, rsyslog, systemd-journal-remote

I am using Rsyslog for distributed log collection. To my understanding, the flow of logs on Debian starts from `journals` then to `syslog socket` and then it is picked up by `rsyslog clients`. In my case, the RS clients are post-processing the logs collected by adding extra information like `time-generated`, `priority`, `hostname` etc. There are **two** `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` that is used on every node:

1. For capturing local logs and showing on terminal (forwarding to spec)
2. For forwarding logs to other nodes

Lately, I am running into following issue:
 - All nodes have same configurations, the forwarding node is adding the post processing information to the logs. When received, before sending to terminal, the local configuration is also adding the post processing information (making is twice). Certain information like `time generated` doesn't get duplicated, but information like hostname is getting printed twice. I have to post process at both times because log server may be `external or internal` and the forwarded v/s local logs should look the same.

- Is this the best way to handle distributed log collection?
- How can I avoid duplicate post processing strings?
- Why is `time-generated` not getting duplicated?

Any pointer would really help, thanks!

Specs:
Nodes: Debian Jessie, Systemd 215,  Rsyslog 8.3.3
Server: Same as above or external rsyslog servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging/digging into documentations, here were my observations:

1. `Rsyslog parser` does its best to identify the log format, especially the header component.
2. Properties like `%time-generated%`, if identified correctly, will not be duplicated at relay/collector.
3. Although my template was aligned to RFC5424, the parser was not picking the format correctly; hence the duplication. Here is the format I was using for reference:
   `<%PRI%>1 %TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %APP-NAME% %PROCID% %MSGID% %STRUCTURED-DATA% %msg%\n`
4. I switched to predefined RFC5424 template `RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format` and every thing seems to be fine now.

Hope this answers everything. Please feel free to discuss this question further :-)
A very good article that helped me understand the nature of rsyslog parser is [this](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/syslog_parsing.html)